# JS manipulate CSS 3D rotating animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I am very new to this CSS animation things and I have followed a tutorial making 3D rotating elements from this site http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/3d-transforms/

This is my rotating 4 sided 3D square: https://jsfiddle.net/k0u8kn4w/

Now I want to use JS to make the side of the square to only rotate once to the second side when I clicked on it. So let's say the initial side is side A (not moving), when I click on it, I want it to rotate to show side B (rotate once 90 deg), when I click on it again, turn to side C, click again then turn to side D, another click turn to side A and so on.

Have tried manipulating the `animation-play-state` with running and paused, doesn't work, tried also manipulating the `rotateY` and `TranslateZ` degree, not sure how to manipulate the `keyframes`, couldn't find it anywhere.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

#stage {
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  -ms-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

#spinner {
  -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#spinner div,
#spinner img {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id='stage' style='height: 160px; width: 180px;'>
  <div id='spinner'>
    <div style='-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0px; background: red; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;' class='rotating'>A</div>
    <div style='-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0; background: blue; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;'>B</div>
    <div style='-webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0; background: green; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;'>C</div>
    <div style='-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0; background: yellow; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;' class='rotating'>D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to resume animation and wait for 1/4 of animation duration.

Simplified your code (removed vendor prefixes, most of browsers work OK without them, but reapply them if needed). Demo:

```js
var spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
// get animation duration in ms
var animationDuration = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(spinner)["animation-duration"]) * 1000;

spinner.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // run animation
  spinner.style["animation-play-state"] = "running";
  // pause animation after animationDuration / 4
  setTimeout(function() {
    spinner.style["animation-play-state"] = "paused";
  }, animationDuration / 4);
});
```

```css
@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

#stage {
  margin: 1em auto;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

#spinner {
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-play-state: paused; /* new */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#spinner div,
#spinner img {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id='stage' style='height: 160px; width: 180px;'>
  <div id='spinner'>
    <div style='transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0px; background: red; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;' class='rotating'>A</div>
    <div style='transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0; background: blue; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;'>B</div>
    <div style='transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0; background: green; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;'>C</div>
    <div style='transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(90px); padding: 0 0; background: yellow; width: 180px; height: 160px; display: inline-block;' class='rotating'>D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```